# Clang: How to wrap a cv-qualified member function with std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

I'm having problem to compile the following code with Clang:

```
#include <functional>

struct C {
    void m() const {}
};

int main() {
    C c;

    std::function<void(C*)> f1 = &C::m;
    f1(&c);

    std::function<void(C&)> f2 = &C::m;
    f2(c);

    std::function<void(C)> f3 = &C::m;
    f3(c);
}
```

The reported error is long and can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/erdavila/f3717d1d51ab07c99805).

GCC is able to compile it.
If the `const` qualifier is removed, the code compiles successfully on both GCC and Clang.

The versions I'm using are: GCC 4.8.4, Clang 3.6.0.

Comment: No problem here : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbb9ec6aa4c64fdd

Comment: Please show the error messages.

Comment: @T.C. , I included a link to the reported error.

Comment: Is this Apple Clang by any chance? The only way I can imagine getting an error the way you did is between [r208825](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=208825), which added the check for nonreferenceable function types to the compiler, and [r209785](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=209785), which fixed (most of) the breakage in libc++, which are two weeks apart and well before the actual 3.6 branch.

Comment: @T.C. I'm very new to Clang/libc++/LLVM. I'm trying to use it on Linux Mint 17.1. Clang and libc++ were installed as regular .deb packages. I wonder if this issue is more on `libc++-dev` than on Clang... The installed version of `libc++` packages is "1.0~svn199600-1" and is the most recent version available as a .deb packages for my system.

Comment: Sounds like you are pairing a new version of clang with an old version of libc++, then. Unsurprising that it's messed up.